# Ejecutable con Pyinstaller no abre archivos PDF

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, pyinstaller

Tengo una aplicación que genera unos informes en PDF con reportlab y posteriormente se abre automáticamente con:

```
os.popen(filename)
```

El problema es que necesito generar un ejecutable, el cual genero con PYINSTALLER. La aplicación funciona perfectamente, de hecho genera bien el archivo PDF pero cuando intenta abrirlo, no lo hace, de hecho se queda colgado Acrobat Reader. Parece problema de PYINSTALLER, existe algún parámetro a la hora de crear el ejecutable que pueda solucionar esto? He probado estas diferentes formas de abrir el archivo sin éxito:

```
os.popen(filename)
subprocess.Popen([filename],shell=True)
os.startfile(filename)
webbrowser.open_new(filename)
```

Comment: Alfredo, cuando generas el ejecutable con pyinstaller, ¿dejas habilitada la consola?. Si es así, entonces podrías indicarnos si obtienes algún error. Por otra parte, has probado abrir el archivo con *subprocess.call([editor, archivo])* ?

Comment: Antes no dejaba abierta la consola, he hecho pruebas dejándola abierta para poder ver que error daba, pero no se obtiene ningún error. Respecto a la llamada CALL, que iría en el parámetro EDITOR??

Comment: El software con que abres el archivo. subprocess.call(["C:/windows/notepad.exe", "archivo_prueba.txt"]), por ejemplo.

Comment: Esa solución no me vale porque no puedo depender de una ruta absoluta a una aplicación.

Comment: Y ya probaste con *os.startfile("nombre_del_archivo.pdf")* ?

Comment: Si, he probado, lo he incluido en la lista de opciones que comento que he usado